# Moving a unique_ptr vs. using get()?

Tags: c++

```
std::unique_ptr<Something> p{...};
f(p.get()); // is this better
f(std::move(p)); // or this?
```

Semantically, I know that the first case is if `f` just wants to do something with `p` but doesn't want to "own" it, whereas the second transfers ownership of `p` to `f` so that afterwards `p` is useless.

But, this is too abstract I'm not sure what some examples of this in practice are. Could I get some examples on cases where I'd want to use `get()` and cases where I'd want to move?

Comment: What is the type of the parameter of `f`?

Comment: I assume f would be declared as `void f(std::unique_ptr<Something> p)`? Should it be anything else, like a pointer or a reference?

Comment: If `f` has a parameter of the unique pointer type, it indicates that it wants to take over the ownership. Then, the second case is appropriate and the first one wrong. "_Should it be anything else, like a pointer or a reference?_" — How can we know? That very much depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I see I see, thanks!

Comment: With this declaration `f(p.get());` wont compile. The [required constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) is marked explicit. I think you already gave a good explanation of what both versions _could_ do, but they still do different things, so it's hard to argue about what is better.

Comment: Taking ownership means that `p` will not be used after `f(...);`. If you want the function to take ownership use `std::move(p)` and argument of type `std::unique_ptr<T>`. If you want the function to simply use the pointer, and let `p` keep using the pointer after, use `p.get()` and argument of type `T*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function does not participate in ownership:

```
int f(Something* p) {
    if (p == nullptr) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

It merely uses the pointer value to do something. It could also dereference the pointer, but it has no buisness in deleting the pointed to object. Not participating in ownership is indicated by taking a raw pointer argument.

Its a contrived example, but this function `f` does participate in ownership:

```
struct foo {
   std::unique_ptr<Something> x;       
};

foo f(std::unique_ptr<Something> x){
    return {std::move(x)};
}
```

It transfers ownership of the `unique_ptr` managed object to the `foo` that is returned. Whoever owned the `Something` before does not own it anymore.